# Tooltip content qTip2 jQuery

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip2

I´m trying to get this to work but it just want...

The alert alerts the correct content.. any ideas?

```
    function initToolTip() {
        $('.product').qtip({
            content: $(this).find('.product-info').html(),
            style: 'ui-tooltip-shadow'
         });
         $('.product').on('hover',function(){
            //alert($(this).find('.product-info').html());
         });
    }
```

Comment: this in the function probably refer to the window object, in the hover event instead refer correctly the .product element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

`$(this)`  is **not in the** context of the `.product` in the first case..

`$(this)` refers to the tooltip object..

Use the custom function to retrieve that ..

```
$('.product').qtip({
            content: {
               text: function(api) {
                return $(this).find('.product-info').html() ;
               }
            },
            style: 'ui-tooltip-shadow'
         });
```

Comment: Haha.. it´s just to late.. I´ll go to bed and fix it tomorrow!.. Thx ;)